# QNEAT3 'Iso-Area as Polygons processing error

Tags: qgis, isochrone, qgis-network-analysis

I am doing a network analysis on QGIS.

Versione di QGIS: 3.28.12-Firenze
Revisione codice QGIS: dcc633b2de
Versione di Qt: 5.15.3
Versione Python: 3.9.5
Versione di GDAL: 3.7.3
Versione di GEOS: 3.12.0-CAPI-1.18.0
Versione di PROJ: Rel. 9.3.0, September 1st, 2023
versione di PDAL: 2.5.5 (git-version: 24f78d)

with QNEAT3 plugin  version 1.0.5

using some point layer  derived from OSM and the line layer from open transport map that is topologicaly correct , also with all the default parameter the processing return the same error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/angel/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\2/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\IsoAreaAsPolygonsFromLayer.py", line 229, in processAlgorithm
net = Qneat3Network(network, input_coordinates, strategy, directionFieldName, forwardValue, backwardValue, bothValue, defaultDirection, analysisCrs, speedFieldName, defaultSpeed, tolerance, feedback)
File "C:\Users/angel/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\2/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Framework.py", line 126, in **init**
self.list_tiedPoints = self.director.makeGraph(self.builder, self.list_input_points, self.feedback)
Exception: unknown

Execution failed after 6.72 second

How can I solve that problem?

[image: this is the error that QNEAT3 give me]

Comment: Have you contacted the plugin provider?

Comment: Please provide the error message as text not as screenshot.